# Append Angular Component to HTMLElement

Tags: angular

I am asynchronously loading an entire form in my Angular Application, which have got multiple input fields, looking like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>
</div>
```

I need to update the DOM to, for instance, add classes to the Labels of the fields, but also add HTML such as a check and error icon to every form field.

I got an `IconComponent`, with a `@Input` for the iconName. So when placing it in a Angular Template it looks like `<icon-component [icon]="'success'"></icon-component>`

So I want to grab the `.form-group`, and append the `IconComponent` inside it, something like:

```
setIcon() {
  const formGroup: Element = document.querySelector('.form-group') // As ViewContainerRef(?)
  formGroup.createComponent(IconComponent) // .. with @Input icon = 'success'
}
```

But I can't set my `document.querySelector` as `ViewContainerRef`, and neither I can set the `@Input` using `viewContainerRef.createComponent`.

I have found lots of examples of the `ComponentFactoryResolver`, but that one is deprecated, so I'd like to avoid that way.

**Edit**

The HTML of my Angular Template only looks like this:

```
<form id="form-holder"></form>
<loader *ngIf="loading"></loader>
```

and the external API initialized the entire form inside `#form-holder`, so my DOM eventually looks like

```
<form id="form-holder">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
    <input type="text" id="birthday"/>
  </div>
  ... etc
</form>
<loader *ngIf="loading"></loader>
```

Comment: Can you create a directive that you can attach to the form field that adds classes with a `@HostBinding('class.some-class')` and an `*ngIf` to hide show an error?

Comment: You might also be able to use a [component outlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) `<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentToRender"></ng-container>`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Thanks for the help, but the HTML of the form-group is not rendered in my Angular Template, it's rendered using some Javascript API. Can I still bind a `@HostBinding` to it to attach an Angular Component later on?

Comment: Can you use the `innerHTML` directive? https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I had added the HTML of my Angular Component. I dont think I can add the `innerHTML` class anywhere, right? Because then I will overwrite the HTML of the form itself.